# Matlab State Space Model Response system

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a following lab where i was asked to  write the command matlab lines for these questions:

[image]

1. If initial Conditions are: x(0)=[2;0]. ℎ  ().
2. Find the response y(t) due to step input with Amplitude of
3. Find the Transfer Function for the above state space model
4. Derive back the state space model from (3).

```
a = [0,1;0,4];
b = [0;1];
c = [0 -5];
x0=[2;0];
sys = ss(a,b,c,2);
initial(sys,x0); % to get 1
[n,d]=ss2tf(a,b,c,0);
mySys_tf=tf(n,d) % to get 3
[num den] = tfdata(mySys_tf, 'v')
tf2ss(num,den) % to get 4
```

**I have written this code but it seems like its not giving me any results in the response graph and thus i can't also solve 2 and it get error in 4 if you can help me out to check what is wrong**

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the error comes from the fact that the system is unstable. If you were to plot the system's reaction to a step input using `step()` then you will see how it goes to infinity. I also don't know how far you are into your controls course and if you've seen the root locus yet, but you can plot the root locus of the system via `rlocus(sys)` and you'll see that the real portion of the root is on the right half of the plane and therefore letting you know that the system is unstable.

Comment: Thank you  we still didn't reach about the stability of the system yet but however i understood what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

1. The response is 0 and will stay zero as `x(2) = 0`. It requires an input `u` to get `x(2)` off zero. So the graph is totally fine.
2. use `step(sys)` and you will see the drop to `-Inf`. Optionally you can define the end-time. Call `step(sys,1)` to see a reasonable range.

You solved 3 & 4 yourself.

To check stability you simply need to ask MATLAB `isstable(sys)` (isn't it continent? Well, there is a danger that people will forget the theory behind it and how it is connected...)
To check observability: `rank(obsv(sys))` and make sure that it is the same as the system matrix

```
assert(rank(obsv(sys)) == length(sys.A), 'System is not observable!')
```

Comment: Find the response y(t) due to step input with Amplitude of 2 i beleive that i don't understand number 2 how can i input a step with amplitude of 2 i made it so it it is written in the code step(sys,2) but i still don't understand how its amplitude due to step response is 2

Comment: Maybe, you should have a look at the docs of [stepdataoptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepdataoptions.html). `step(sys,2)` does **not** use a step amplitude of 2 **but** simulates the model for 2 seconds (as I wrote above). `step(sys,stepDataOptions('StepAmplitude',2))` will give you what you want